# Need a script or command to append the previous line with the current line that starts with a lower case letter

Tags: shell-script, sed, text-formatting

The output I'm trying to format before opening the file in excel looks like this:

```
1. |1.99934| BD | 1| C   1 - H   2
| 60.12%|   0.7754* C   1 s| 24.99%|p 3.00| 74.95%|d 0.00|  0.05%|
f 0.00|  0.01%|
| 39.88%|   0.6315* H   2 s| 99.94%|p 0.00|  0.06%|
2. |1.99934| BD | 1| C   1 - H   3
| 60.12%|   0.7754* C   1 s| 24.99%|p 3.00| 74.95%|d 0.00|  0.05%|
f 0.00|  0.01%|
| 39.88%|   0.6315* H   3 s| 99.94%|p 0.00|  0.06%|
3. |1.99934| BD | 1| C   1 - H   4
| 60.12%|   0.7754* C   1 s| 24.99%|p 3.00| 74.95%|d 0.00|  0.05%|
f 0.00|  0.01%|
| 39.88%|   0.6315* H   4 s| 99.94%|p 0.00|  0.06%|
4. |1.99934| BD | 1| C   1 - H   5
| 60.12%|   0.7754* C   1 s| 24.99%|p 3.00| 74.95%|d 0.00|  0.05%|
f 0.00|  0.01%|
| 39.88%|   0.6315* H   5 s| 99.94%|p 0.00|  0.06%|
```

I would like a way to add lines that starts with "f" to the previous line so the output would look like this:

```
1. |1.99934| BD | 1| C   1 - H   2
| 60.12%|   0.7754* C   1 s| 24.99%|p 3.00| 74.95%|d 0.00|  0.05%|f 0.00|  0.01%|
| 39.88%|   0.6315* H   2 s| 99.94%|p 0.00|  0.06%|
2. |1.99934| BD | 1| C   1 - H   3
| 60.12%|   0.7754* C   1 s| 24.99%|p 3.00| 74.95%|d 0.00|  0.05%|f 0.00|  0.01%|
| 39.88%|   0.6315* H   3 s| 99.94%|p 0.00|  0.06%|
3. |1.99934| BD | 1| C   1 - H   4
| 60.12%|   0.7754* C   1 s| 24.99%|p 3.00| 74.95%|d 0.00|  0.05%|f 0.00|  0.01%|
| 39.88%|   0.6315* H   4 s| 99.94%|p 0.00|  0.06%|
4. |1.99934| BD | 1| C   1 - H   5
| 60.12%|   0.7754* C   1 s| 24.99%|p 3.00| 74.95%|d 0.00|  0.05%|f 0.00|  0.01%|
| 39.88%|   0.6315* H   5 s| 99.94%|p 0.00|  0.06%|
```

My attempts at trying to do this with SED are not working! HELP!!

Comment: `sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\nf/f/;ta' -e 'P;D' file` should do it - it's essentially another variant of the standard sed one-liner that appends a line to the previous one if it starts with a specific marker (usually `=`). See for example [USEFUL ONE-LINE SCRIPTS FOR SED](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt)

Comment: Can you please add your attempts to the question? Do you have GNU sed? If yes, with the `-z` flag you can match a newline followed by `f` and make the substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Using `paste`:

```
$ paste -d '\n\0\n\n' - - - - <file
1. |1.99934| BD | 1| C   1 - H   2
| 60.12%|   0.7754* C   1 s| 24.99%|p 3.00| 74.95%|d 0.00|  0.05%|f 0.00|  0.01%|
| 39.88%|   0.6315* H   2 s| 99.94%|p 0.00|  0.06%|
2. |1.99934| BD | 1| C   1 - H   3
| 60.12%|   0.7754* C   1 s| 24.99%|p 3.00| 74.95%|d 0.00|  0.05%|f 0.00|  0.01%|
| 39.88%|   0.6315* H   3 s| 99.94%|p 0.00|  0.06%|
3. |1.99934| BD | 1| C   1 - H   4
| 60.12%|   0.7754* C   1 s| 24.99%|p 3.00| 74.95%|d 0.00|  0.05%|f 0.00|  0.01%|
| 39.88%|   0.6315* H   4 s| 99.94%|p 0.00|  0.06%|
4. |1.99934| BD | 1| C   1 - H   5
| 60.12%|   0.7754* C   1 s| 24.99%|p 3.00| 74.95%|d 0.00|  0.05%|f 0.00|  0.01%|
| 39.88%|   0.6315* H   5 s| 99.94%|p 0.00|  0.06%|
```

Since it looks like you want to remove the 2nd newline from every group of four lines, the above `paste` command does just that.

Answer (score 1):

In ex:

```
printf '%s\n' g/^f/-1j wq | ex file
```

This uses the `g`lobal command to run `-1j`oin on all the lines starting with `f`. Join simply joins lines.

Comment: This does not work properly with `ed` for me, but does work with `ex`... I am not sure if the global command accepts ranges in the pattern slot or if this is a Vim extension.

Comment: @Quasímodo could be. I’ll update

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` for any number of lines in a group and starting with any lower case letter ....

```
awk -v ORS= '{print (($0!~"^[a-z]"&&NR>1)?"\n":"")$0}END{ print "\n"}' file
```

Set `ORS` to empty and print `\n` before `$0` whenever `$0` doesn't start with a lower case letter remembering not to put `\n` before the first line.

Output

```
1. |1.99934| BD | 1| C   1 - H   2
| 60.12%|   0.7754* C   1 s| 24.99%|p 3.00| 74.95%|d 0.00|  0.05%|f 0.00|  0.01%|
| 39.88%|   0.6315* H   2 s| 99.94%|p 0.00|  0.06%|
2. |1.99934| BD | 1| C   1 - H   3
| 60.12%|   0.7754* C   1 s| 24.99%|p 3.00| 74.95%|d 0.00|  0.05%|f 0.00|  0.01%|
| 39.88%|   0.6315* H   3 s| 99.94%|p 0.00|  0.06%|
3. |1.99934| BD | 1| C   1 - H   4
| 60.12%|   0.7754* C   1 s| 24.99%|p 3.00| 74.95%|d 0.00|  0.05%|f 0.00|  0.01%|
| 39.88%|   0.6315* H   4 s| 99.94%|p 0.00|  0.06%|
4. |1.99934| BD | 1| C   1 - H   5
| 60.12%|   0.7754* C   1 s| 24.99%|p 3.00| 74.95%|d 0.00|  0.05%|f 0.00|  0.01%|
| 39.88%|   0.6315* H   5 s| 99.94%|p 0.00|  0.06%|
```

**Note:** basically does the same as @steeldriver `sed` response in the comments if you replace the search `f` with regex in a capture group `\n([a-z])`and reinsert the captured character `\1`.

I just find `awk` more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (/^f/ ? "" : s), $0; s=ORS} END{print ""}' file
1. |1.99934| BD | 1| C   1 - H   2
| 60.12%|   0.7754* C   1 s| 24.99%|p 3.00| 74.95%|d 0.00|  0.05%|f 0.00|  0.01%|
| 39.88%|   0.6315* H   2 s| 99.94%|p 0.00|  0.06%|
2. |1.99934| BD | 1| C   1 - H   3
| 60.12%|   0.7754* C   1 s| 24.99%|p 3.00| 74.95%|d 0.00|  0.05%|f 0.00|  0.01%|
| 39.88%|   0.6315* H   3 s| 99.94%|p 0.00|  0.06%|
3. |1.99934| BD | 1| C   1 - H   4
| 60.12%|   0.7754* C   1 s| 24.99%|p 3.00| 74.95%|d 0.00|  0.05%|f 0.00|  0.01%|
| 39.88%|   0.6315* H   4 s| 99.94%|p 0.00|  0.06%|
4. |1.99934| BD | 1| C   1 - H   5
| 60.12%|   0.7754* C   1 s| 24.99%|p 3.00| 74.95%|d 0.00|  0.05%|f 0.00|  0.01%|
| 39.88%|   0.6315* H   5 s| 99.94%|p 0.00|  0.06%|
```